# How keys and value pair can be in order During json parsing in java when format is unknown?

Tags: java, json, parsing

Have in mind that the JSON structure is not known before hand i.e. it is completely arbitrary, we only know that it is JSON format.

---

How can we get the data in order while we know HASHMAP not take care of order of data.
We can do this to traverse the tree and keep track of how deep we want to figure out dot notation property names.

---

but this should be in proper order because we know HashMap not take of order of data. Any alternative ways to acheive this problem.

```
key:0.address.city, : value  Gwenborough
Key:0.address.geo.lng, : value  81.1496
Key:0.name, : value  Leanne Graham
Key:0.username, : value  Bret
```

Comment: Have you tried LinkedHashMap that keeps original order?

Comment: @MikhailKopylov Not yet

Comment: Then it's worth trying

Comment: @MikhailKopylov I update the code.But Array index came along the current path like key:0.address.city, : value  Gwenborough but i want only to diplay like this address.city : value  Gwenborough.

Comment: @MikhailKopylov how can we get data for single line like address.street at run time

Comment: it seems correct since your JSON is effectively an array of objects, so `0` is an inject of element in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using LinkedHashMap instead - it supports original order.